# Keep user logged in when opening new page: google sign in

Tags: javascript, api, session

I'm integrating google sign in with my website and this is what I have done so far when the user logs in for the first time.

1. get user profile/id_token from the google sign in button [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in)
2. Verify that token with server backend [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth)
3. Add user "sub"(id) to database if the user is new and token has been verified.

Now, when the user is logged in and opens another page I execute this code to get user id/sub:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=apiloaded" async defer></script>


<script>

function apiloaded(){
    var auth2;

gapi.load('auth2', function() {
  auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
    client_id: 'MY_CLIENT_ID_IS_HERE',
    fetch_basic_profile: false,
    scope: 'profile'
  });

  // Sign the user in, and then retrieve their ID.
  auth2.signIn().then(function() {
    console.log(auth2.currentUser.get().getId());
  });
});

}
</script>
```

Doing this opens an external windows that signs in the user and returns the user id and then closes automatically.

My questions are

1. how can I do this without having an external window to open at every page.
2. Is this safe?

**Edit:**

I've decided to keep the user logged in vie php sessions instead. It seems much more secure are easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

To do this without opening a new window (and to do this safely) you would need to be using a server side language to handle the sign-in/authentication process. :D

I've not done it but perhaps you could keep the session stored via cookies so you don't have to do it on every page, but *ideally* your back end would be the one storing these tokens and passing them to your front end, not the other way around.